# 301 redirect file to clean url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Working on redirects for my page. I have a list of all the old and new urls.

The old urls are /directory/subdirectory/file.php

The new urls are clean urls

/directory/subdirectory/file/

Some new urls match the old urls without the ".php" while some other do not.

One webpage suggested:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/sales/products/item$ /products/item-name/
```

But would the following give me a redirect loop?

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/privacy-policy$ /privacy-policy/
```

I haven't tried it yet, but hoping to not get myself in trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Using Apache's mod_rewrite -- add these lines into your `.htaccess` file:

```
# Activate Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine On

# redirect *.php to "nice" url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1/ [R=301,QSA]

# process "nice" urls by looking for appropriate .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

These rules will do 2 things:

1) redirect (301) *.php to "nice" urls: `directory/subdirectory/file.php` will become `directory/subdirectory/file/`

2) properly serves such "nice" urls, e.g. `directory/subdirectory/file/` will be treated as `directory/subdirectory/file.php`.

**P.S.** If redirect does not work (may happen sometimes depending on configuration) try adding slash before $1 (e.g. `/$1` )

Comment: Thanks, but what about for pages that have a different url name? I have some old pages at /directory/subdirectory/file.php that need to redirect to /new-url-name/

Comment: There are few ways you can do this. The simplest (possibly, it depends on details) would be creating more rewrite rules specifically for those URLs. Can you give few examples please (from => to) as well as approximate number of such redirects.